# Is Java method overloading is static binding?

Tags: java, binding, static

I'm new to Java and confused with static binding. Some sites explain method overloading is static binding. My understanding is only ***Static***, ***Final*** and ***Private*** methods are bind statically. In below example, I think ***print*** method (two overloaded ***print*** methods in SuperClass) is bind dynamically not statically because sub class ***print*** method can override the super class ***print*** method during run time. Is only ***Static***, ***Final*** and ***Private*** methods are bind statically and the rest (***public, protected ...***) are dynamically bind ? Please correct me.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Binding
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Collection<String> col = new HashSet<>();
        col.add("hello");
        SuperClass sdObj1 = new SuperClass();
        sdObj1.print(col);
        SuperClass sdObj2 = new SubClass();
        sdObj2.print(col);
        }
    }

class SuperClass
    {
    void print(Collection<String> col)
        {
        System.out.println("SuperClass1");
        }

    void print(HashSet<String> hs)
        {
        System.out.println("SuperClass2");
        }
    }

class SubClass extends SuperClass
    {
    void print(Collection<String> col)
        {
        System.out.println("SubClass");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381292/method-binding-in-java

Comment: So basically, yes. Overload resolution first statically decides which method to pick, but the overridden method executed at runtime is determined based on the runtime type of the object method is invoked on.